# how to print variable name from *args in python

Tags: python

I have defined a function taking a variable number of arguments.

These arguments will all be lists of floats, each variable having a name, say `a`, `b`, `c`, for 3 arguments. They will look like:

```
a=[1,2]
b=[3,4]
c=[5,6]
```

I want to be able to work with the name of these arguments, i.e.

```
def function(*args):
    for arg in args:
        plt.plot(x_value, arg, label="the name of arg")
```

I call the function as `function(a,b,c)`

`"the name of arg"` shall be the string `a` for the first iteration of the for loop, the string `b` for the second iteration of the for loop and the string `c` for the third iteration of the for loop.

What shall I put there at `label=`  ? I have tried various approaches, they all result either in printing the string `arg`, or the actual value of `arg`, i.e. [1,2] for the first iteration of the for-loop.

Thank you!

Comment: Use `**kwargs` instead, that way you will get a dictionary

Comment: If you need that string, then you have to pass that string. When you pass an argument to a function, their is no information about the names of the variables involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the argument names, you have to use named arguments or a dictionary.

```
def function(**kwargs):
    for name, value in kwargs.items():
        plt.plot(x_value, value, label=name)

function(a=a, b=b, c=c)
```

This passes three named arguments to the function, `a`, `b`, and `c`.